# Rendering HTML Tags from within CDATA tag in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I have a CDATA tag within my XML code which contains some hyperlinks.

```
<smartText><![CDATA[
Among individual stocks, the top percentage gainers in the S.&P. 500 are
<a href ='http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=LNC'>Lincoln National Corp</a> and 
<a href ='http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=PLD'>ProLogis</a>.]]>
</smartText>
```

I am trying to transform it into an HTML page as follows...

```
<p class="smartText">
    <xsl:copy-of select="marketSummaryModuleData/smartText"/>                                    
</p>
```

Unfortunately the output onto the page shows up in pure text, not as html.

```
Among individual stocks, the top percentage gainers in the S.&P. 500 are <a href ='http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?ric=PLD'>ProLogis</a> and <a href ='http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?ric=LNC'>Lincoln National Corp</a>.
```

The CDATA section is being created from a classic ASP page, so the actual XML output does not contain the CDATA section.  Could that be part of the problem?  I cannot seem to get the information to render on the page.  I have tried multiple solutions offered up by Google searches, such as disable-escape-tags, xsl:copy-of, xsl:value-of and more.

Thank you

Comment: Final solution...  Please see this posting.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706314/hyperlinks-within-xslt-templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have to correct the XML so that the desired HTML (and it needs to be well-formed XML) is not contained within a CDATA section**.

Any CDATA section is just part of a text() node and the XSLT processor treats it as such.

Putting markup within CDATA is universally acknowledged as bad practice and the reported issue is one typical result.

DOE (disable-output-escaping) is an optional feature in XSLT and is not guaranteed to be implemented and producing the same expected results on different XSLT processors.

To quote the [**W3C XSLT Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping).:

`"An XSLT processor is not required to support disabling output escaping. If an xsl:value-of or xsl:text specifies that output escaping should be disabled and the XSLT processor does not support this, the XSLT processor may signal an error; if it does not signal an error, it must recover by not disabling output escaping.
"`

and:

`"Since disabling output escaping may not work with all XSLT processors and can result in XML that is not well-formed, it should be used only when there is no alternative."`

Comment: @Tomalak d-o-e may or maynot solve the OP's problem, depending on which XSLT processor (s)he is using.

Comment: disable-output-escaping does work, but not in all browsers.  Since this module will be used by thousands of people, it will need to work in all browsers.  It looks like I will need to take the data in my ASP code and parse it into multiple tags instead of one large string of text.

Comment: @Shane: you should add the detail that you need to work in all browsers in your question.  Would a server-side transform work for you?

Comment: It would be nice to transform on the server side, but since this is a cross-domain solution, it will need to be transformed on the client-side.

Comment: Since this segment has the most information in it I am marking this as the right answer.

The other answer is correct too, but not for all browsers.  Was trying to take a shortcut by inserting HTML into the tags, but now I've realized that I really need to break out the info into well formed XML.

Answer (score 11):

```
<p class="smartText">
  <xsl:value-of 
    select="marketSummaryModuleData/smartText" 
    disable-output-escaping="yes"
  />
</p>
```

EDIT: As @Randell points out in the comments, `disable-output-escaping` is not present in all XSLT processors. For instance, the one in Firefox does not support this attribute. The above won't work for these processors. All *stand-alone* XSLT processors I know support it, though.

Comment: @Randell: It's not clear at all from the question that the XSLT transformation is being done in a browser.

Comment: Could you expound on this a bit?

Comment: @Randell: Not sure what you mean. For my part, any XSLT I do runs on a server of some sort. I have not yet encountered a situation where disable-output-escaping was not available in a server environment.

Comment: Interesting. I've only used XSLT for browsers. What kind of data do you process on the server? Also, if you may edit your answer, I can cancel my downvote.

Comment: @Randell: Probably the same data that you would send to the client along with an XSLT stylesheet. I like being in control over the conversion process and being independent, so it runs on all clients down to smart phones. Same with RSS - if you're going to convert XML to RSS, the place to do it is on the server. XSLT capabilities of different clients have always been too inconsistent for my tastes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="marketSummaryModuleData/smartText">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:for-each>

<smartText>
Among individual stocks, the top percentage gainers in the S.&P. 500 are
<a href ='http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=LNC'>Lincoln National Corp</a> and 
<a href ='http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=PLD'>ProLogis</a>.
</smartText>
```