# Hyperlinks within XSLT Templates

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create hyperlinks using XML information and XSLT templates.  Here is the XML source.

```
<smartText>
Among individual stocks, the top percentage gainers in the S. and P. 500 are 
<smartTextLink smartTextRic="http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=HBAN.O">Huntington Bancshares Inc</smartTextLink>
and 
<smartTextLink smartTextRic="http://investing.domain.com/research/stocks/snapshot
/snapshot.asp?ric=EK">Eastman Kodak Co</smartTextLink>
.
</smartText>
```

I want the output to look like this, with the company names being hyperlinks based on the "smartTextLink" tags in the Xml.

Among individual stocks, the top percentage gainers in the S.&P. 500 are Eastman Kodak Co and Huntington Bancshares Inc.

Here are the templates that I am using right now.  I can get the text to display, but not the hyperlinks.

```
<xsl:template match="smartText">
  <p class="smartText">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="smartTextLink">
  <a>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@smartTextRic"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </a> 
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried multiple variations to try to get the hyperlinks to work correctly.  I am thinking that the template match="smartTextLink" is not being instantiated for some reason.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this work?

EDIT:  After reviewing some of the answers, it is still not working in my overall application.

I am calling the smartText template from within my main template

using the following statement...

```
<xsl:value-of select="marketSummaryModuleData/smartText"/>
```

Could this also be a part of the problem?

Thank you

Shane

Comment: Use "<xsl:apply-tempates select="marketSummaryModuleData/smartText" />", instead of "<xsl:value-of ... />".

Comment: Since this is in the middle of a <div> I am getting a parsing error.

Comment: This is not possible, you can use "apply-tempates" any place where "value-of" would work. Can you post more context? I guess the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I was able to clear the error.  It was a typo.  It is now working, using the first solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either move the `xsl:attribute` before any children, or use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

```
<xsl:template match="smartTextLink">
    <a href="{@smartTextRic}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a> 
</xsl:template>
```

From the [creating attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) section of the XSLT 1 spec:

> The following are all errors:
>
> - Adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to it; implementations may either signal the error or ignore the attribute.

Comment: A naked <xsl:apply-templates /> would suffice.

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be critical. It was just a comment. :-)

Comment: This worked.  The problem was partly due to the way that I was applying the template within my main template.  Thanks you to all!

Answer (score 5):

Try this - worked for me:

```
<xsl:template match="smartText">
    <p class="smartText">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="smartTextLink">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@smartTextRic"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
```

Trick is - `<xsl:attribute>` first, before you do any other processing.

Marc

Comment: The <xsl:attribute> was not visible therefore your answer seemed a bit strange. Just corrected it. (and +1)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  This was helpful,  Even though I did not vote it the correct answer (the other answer required fewer lines of code.).  I did vote this one up.

Thanks to all!