# Display a clickable link out of a XML file on a website with CDATA

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, cdata

I am programming in VB. And currently displaying some XML on a Webpage.
I would like to display a clickable link. So I tried:

```
Dim objXml As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
objXml.LoadXml(pInfo.AsXml)
Dim outerXML = Replace(objXml.OuterXml(), "<MID>someText</MID>", "<MID><![CDATA[<a href='https://www.google.com'>Click me</a>]]></MID>")
```

But it actually displays just all the text and does not format the html inside CDATA:

```
<MID><a href='https://www.google.com'>Click me</a></MID>
```

All it should display is:

```
<MID>Click me</MID>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like so with double quotes:

```
Dim outerXml as String = Replace(objXml.OuterXml(), "<MID>someText</MID>", "<MID><![CDATA[<a href=""https://www.google.com"">Click me</a>]]></MID>")
```

or

```
Dim outerXml as String
outerXML = Replace(objXml.OuterXml(), "<MID>someText</MID>", "<MID><![CDATA[<a href=""https://www.google.com"">Click me</a>]]></MID>")
```

You could also use xml.WriteCdata with xml writer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Now it is still just displaying all the text like <MID><a href='https://www.google.com'>Click me</a></MID>

Comment: When you use triple quotes sets href="""https://www.google.com""", sorry I used double quote sets

Comment: I think what you are looking for has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706314/hyperlinks-within-xslt-templates