# How can you deal with embedded XML tags in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, formatting

I am using XSLT to convert XML to HTML. I am having trouble figuring out how to deal with embedded XML nodes for formatting. For example, let's say I have the XML element:

`<favoriteMovie>the <i>Star Wars</i> saga</favoriteMovie>`

However, during XLST, the `<i>` tag gets ignored, so "Star Wars" is not italicized in the HTML output. Is there a relatively simple way to fix this?

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.html.xsl"?>
<favoriteMovies>
    <favoriteMovie>the <i>Star Wars</i> saga</favoriteMovie>
</favoriteMovies>
```

test.html.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head />
          <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="favoriteMovies/favoriteMovie">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
          </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the cause of the problem and two complete and short solutions. Do note that the currently accepted answer is completely wrong. Putting markup into a CDATA section converts this into unusable, 1-dimentional text and is generally identified as a bad practice.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, unless there's absolutely no NEED to treat that html as structured, and its only purpose is to be passed to the browser as-is with no risk of breaking the original XML structure with arbitraty html tags.

Comment: Let's get to understanding before placing judgments on each other. Please, elaborate on the "destroyed markup", I'm not following you.

Comment: @etranger: You can very easily find why destroying markup is bad practice -- just search. You may start with this: http://xml.silmaril.ie/cdata.html , but there are numerous other sources which you can easily find.

Comment: the code here http://pastie.org/1468206 produces this output http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16517379/xslt-ss.png, I can't seem to understand why the markup is "destroyed". In essence: provided solution works, and was originally marked by OP as working. I have my arguments too. Let's talk and clear this out.

Comment: PS your link on cdata describes _exactly_ my original point. <i> doesn't belong to the favoriteMovies xml tree. It's from a different domain.

Comment: You cant claim i doesn't belong to favoriteMovies as there are no namespaces or schemas involved anywhere. It's just an assumption. If favoriteMovies contains no definition of it's content then an i element is just as valid as favoriteMovie. If there was a namespace for the original XML and i wasn't included in it then the correct approach would be to deal with the namespace, rather than deal with xml formatted text as a string.

Comment: @etranger: The mere fact that you have to resort to DOE shows that you have created a mess that you have to clean using DOE. Are you aware of the fact that DOE is not a mandatory XSLT feature and is *not* supported by all XSLT processors -- the most notable example being the one used by FireFox? It is an established good principle of XSLT development to avoid using DOE except when no other solution is possible. Please, read and learn.

Comment: I do claim that absolutely obvious HTML markup is placed in XML tree for the purpose of being parsed and rendered by the client browser _only_, and lack of namespaces implies the deficiency in planning the schema. It's just simpler that way. I do claim that html tags that are definitely inserted in xml for the purpose of markup _will_ interfere with the structure of favoriteMovies in ways not intended by the author and hence must be excluded from parsing by xslt processor. Discuss.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I only wish you paid attention to my comments without quick judgments. You haven't replied to my question on destroyed markup, and jumped to argument that DOE is not supported by all processors, while this is nowhere near the discussion. Namespaces would be a better approach than DOE, I agree to that, but not to calling me ignorant, if I may.

Comment: @James Walford, agreed that namespaces would be a proper way, provided that it's XHTML, and not HTML. Which is not necessarily the case here, provided the millions of sites with xml-invalid markup out there.

Comment: @etranger Again, assumptions. If the intended purpose of the database is to preserve snippets of html for rendering in a client browser then it's a perfectly legitimate approach. Excluding them from parsing by xslt processor only serves to make it difficult to strip the tags should another use be found - such as the plain text file he also wishes to create. Given a start point of "my xml contains well formed html elements" there is no good reason to pre-process them to CDATA when they can be handled simply by XSLT.

Comment: @James Walford, agreed on the start point. I'd also suggest the author to use a separate namespace for the favoriteMovies structure to prevent problems in the future.

Comment: @etranger again, that would depend very much on the intended use of the application. In many cases it would simply be overkill.

Comment: @etranger: DOE and namespaces are not significantly related at all. Please, read the Specs.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - to be fair I think @etranger is conceding that namespacing would be a better approach than CDATA and DOE. Personally I don't see a need for namespaces in this example.

Comment: @James-Walford: Yes, I also don't see why namespaces should be counterposed to DOE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However, during XLST, the `<i>` tag gets
>   ignored, so "Star Wars" is not
>   italicized in the HTML output. Is
>   there a relatively simple way to fix
>   this?

**Your problem is here**:

> ```
> <ul>
>   <xsl:for-each select="favoriteMovies/favoriteMovie">
>     <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
>   </xsl:for-each>
> </ul>
> ```

The **[`<xsl:value-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#value-of)** instruction is used to create a text node. In doing so it copies to the output the string value of the XPath expression specified in the `select` attribute of this XSLT instruction. The string value of an element is the concatenation of all its text-node descendents.

So this is how you get the reported output.

**Solution**:

**Use the [`<xsl:copy-of>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#copy-of) instruction**, which copies all the nodes that are specified in its `select` attribute:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="favoriteMovies/favoriteMovie">
    <li><xsl:copy-of select="node()"/></li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

**Another solution, more alligned with the principles of XSLT** avoids using `<xsl:for-each>` at all:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head />
    <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <ul>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="favoriteMovie">
  <li><xsl:copy-of select="node()"/></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When any of the two solutions defined above are applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<favoriteMovies>
    <favoriteMovie>the 
        <i>Star Wars</i> saga
    </favoriteMovie>
</favoriteMovies>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>the 
                <i>Star Wars</i> saga
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it is simpler and works without breaking my plain text XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: @James-Walford: There is one issue with your answer: You cannot know in advance what html elements would be in a `favoriteMovie`, therefore supplying separate templates matching any possible html element is unrealistic. If you really want to avoid using `xsl:copy-of` you need to use the identity rule. I didn't provide a solution with the identity rule, because this goes too-far from the original question.

Comment: I should be able to figure this out, but if I want to do the same thing and I always have a single node instead of multiple, what would the XSL syntax look like? I tried changing <xsl:value-of select="title" /> to <xsl:copy-of select="title" />, but then the <title> tag shows up in the raw HTML and it doesn't render correctly.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev thanks - good point, my answer was based on it being only i elements.

Comment: Got it: <xsl:copy-of select="title/node()" />

Answer (score 2):

You should use xsl:copy to copy the i node  .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256128.aspx

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head />
          <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>        
          </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="favoriteMovies">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
  </ul>  
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="favoriteMovie">
    <li>      
      <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This would be a wrong way to do it generally, because <i> doesn't come from the source XML namespace, but HTML namespace and should be treated that way, or not as a tag at all and hence as part of CDATA.

Comment: There's no indication that there are any namespace references in his XML, and he's attempting to output html anyway. His input doesn't include CDATA, so there seems little point in telling him how he should process it if it did.

Comment: The point is, his code can contain any html tags, including malformed text etc, it shouldn't be treated the same way you treat source xml. please get my idea that it's not about formal namespaces, but rather the logical scope of use of <favoriteMovies> as structure and <i> as markup

Comment: As far as I can see your comment is more relevant to the construction of the original XML. If it contains unclosed HTML elements that aren't in CDATA then it won't be well formed anyway. If his XML is well formed but just happens to contain some HTML elements, with no explicit namespacing, then merely copying them out isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'disable-output-escaping' attribute. The general format of  element is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="expression" disable-output-escaping="yes|no" />
```

'disable-output-escaping' is optional. "yes" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as is. "no" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as "<". Default is "no".

Therefore just change your code to:

```
<xsl:template match="favoriteMovie">
  <xsl:copy-of select="node()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do I get `'disable-output-escaping' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:copy-of' element.` ?

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` is not universally supported and its use is discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/701793/130121

Answer (score -7):

Two things to note.

First. Make sure tags are screened in CDATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.html.xsl"?>
<favoriteMovies>
    <favoriteMovie><![CDATA[the <i>Star Wars</i> saga]]></favoriteMovie>
</favoriteMovies>
```

Second. Disable output escaping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head />
      <body>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="favoriteMovies/favoriteMovie">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: managed it with the editor, now the code is shown as it should

EDIT2: included changes in your code

EDIT3: To whom it may concern, the very domain of the problem in question is about structuring movies information, and not html data. HTML is there for markup purposes only, imagine having, say, *html* title tag inside favoriteMovie, whereas the same named tag title could be a valid tag in the *movies* database. These title's CLEARLY have to be interpreted differently. This justifies using CDATA and then disabling output when processing.

Comment: 1. Doesn't work as expected; the HTML ends up looking like: the &lt;i&gt;Star Wars&lt;/i&gt; saga

Comment: Using gt and lt entities was my attempt to counteract editor problems, don't use them in your document. The point is to use CDATA to wrap HTML tags inside XML tags.

Comment: 2. Doesn't seem to change anything, the <i> tag is still ignored

Comment: I tried 1. with <i>, not &lt;i&gt; but it doesn't work as expected. It shows up in the raw HTML like I specified above in my previous comment, and in the rendered HTML it shows up as "the <i>Star Wars</i> saga" which is obviously not what I was intending.

Comment: You have to do both, wrap html in CDATA and use disable-output-escaping="yes" when using value-of. Please post related complete code if you want us to see where the error is.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, all along I thought you were giving me two different options for doing it! Works great. I am actually doing an XSLT from XML to HTML and a simple text file at the same time--I don't suppose there is an easy way to prevent the <i> tags from showing up in the text file is there?

Comment: As soon as you've put your i tags in CDATA sections you've told your XML processor to treat them as strings, they are no longer xml nodes and if you want to remove them you'll have to parse them as strings.

Comment: If you use the answer I give below then you can change the xsl:copy to xsl:value-of to output the content of the i node without the tag.

Comment: Re: EDIT 3 - you seem to be attempting to answer a question he hasn't asked.